# How to write program to do file transfer based on based omniORBpy

Tags: python, corba, omniorb

I'm now writing a Corba project to do file transfering between client and server.
But I face trouble when I want to upload file from the client to the server.

The IDL I defined is:

```
interface SecretMessage
{
    string send_file(in string file_name, in string file_obj);
};
```

And I implemented the uploading function in the client code:

```
f = open('SB.docx', 'rb')
data = ''
for piece in read_in_chunks(f):
    data += piece

result = mo.send_file('2.docx', data)
```

If the file is a plain txt file, there is no problem.
But if the file is a, like jpg, doc, or others except txt, then it does work.
It gives me the error:

```
omniORB.CORBA.BAD_PARAM: CORBA.BAD_PARAM(omniORB.BAD_PARAM_WrongPythonType, CORBA.COMPLETED_NO)
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is because by default omniORB wants to see ASCII data for strings. Try changing your IDL to this

```
interface SecretMessage
{
    typedef sequence<octet> OctetSequence;
    string send_file(in string file_name, in OctetSequence file_obj);
};
```

You can keep your Python client code the same because in the IDL to Python mapping, octet sequences map to Python strings.